# How to link v4l2src to capsfilter in c for gstreamer-1.14

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2, gstreamer-1.0

I have a gstreamer media pipeline as shown below which I am trying to convert into a c code. The command line works fine.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=UYVY ! queue ! videoconvert ! queue ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1280,height=720,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls="controls,h264_level=12,h264_profile=1" ! h264parse ! autovideosink
```

I have written the code and compilation is successful. When, I execute the code, the videosrc element is unable to link to capsfilter. I have surfed through the internet and was unsuccessful in rectifying the problem. Can someone help in correcting me what, I am doing wrong.

The code snippet is below:

```
/* Create the gstreamer elements */
source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "Caps-Filter");
capsfilter2 = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "caps-filter2");

video_convert = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "Video Convert");

queue1 = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "Encoded Video Queue 1");
queue2 = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "Encoded Video Queue 2");

encoder = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2h264enc", "HW Accelerated Encoder");
H264_pay = gst_element_factory_make ("h264parse", "Payload-encode H264 video into RTP packets");
sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink");

/* Create the empty pipeline */
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

if(!source || !capsfilter || ! capsfilter2 || !video_convert || !queue1 || !queue2 || !encoder || !H264_pay || !sink)

/* Set Source element properties */
g_object_set (G_OBJECT(source), "device", "/dev/video1", NULL);

GstCaps* filtercaps = gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=(string)UYUY");
GstCaps* vconvertfilter = gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=(string)NV12,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1");

GstStructure *test = gst_structure_new_from_string("controls,h264_level=12,h264_profile=1");

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(capsfilter), "caps", filtercaps,NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(capsfilter2), "caps", vconvertfilter, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT(encoder), "extra-controls", test, NULL);

gst_caps_unref(filtercaps);
gst_caps_unref(vconvertfilter);


/* Link all elements that can be automatically linked because they have "Always" pads */
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), 
                            source, capsfilter, 
                            queue1, video_convert, queue2, 
                            capsfilter2, encoder, 
                            H264_pay, sink, NULL);

if(!gst_element_link(source, capsfilter))
{
    g_printerr("Unable to link Source to filter. check your caps. \n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
}


if (gst_element_link_many (capsfilter, queue1, video_convert, NULL) != TRUE)
{
    g_printerr("Capsfilter could not be linked to queue1. \n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
}


if (gst_element_link_many (video_convert, queue2, capsfilter2, encoder, H264_pay, NULL) != TRUE)
{
    g_printerr("video_convert could not be linked to queue2. \n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
}


if(gst_element_link_many (H264_pay, sink, NULL) != TRUE)
{
    g_printerr("parse could not link to sink.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
}
```

I get the error as below;

```
Unable to link Source to filter. check your caps.
```

Can somebody help me correct the mistake?

Comment: Looks surprizing that first pipeline runs fine, as it sends h264 video to autovideosink that may expect raw video instead... Maybe I've missed something in updates of autovideosink, if this really works you would try using `gst_parse_launch` with same pipeline that would negociate caps similar to gst-launch, rather than building yourself the pipeline.

Comment: @SeB At later stage, I have to change the pipeline dynamically which I assume cannot be done in `gst_parse_launch`. So I think, going way forward I would eventually have to go via this method.